# Google App Scriptsで<meta>が反映されない

Tags: html, google-apps-script

Google App Scriptsでスマホ向けのWebページを作りたいと考えているのですが、デプロイしても以下の`<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">`が反映されず、スマホで見た際に、PC用ページのように表示されてしまいます。解決方法教えていただきたいです。
補足ですが、フォントサイズなどの変更は反映されるので、デプロイに失敗してるなどではないかと思います。

- Google App Scriptsでのコード

```
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Spreadsheet Editor</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <style>
        body {
            font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
            margin: 20px;
            font-size: 20px;
        }
        @media (max-width: 600px) {
            body {
                font-size: 20px;
            }

            table, th, td {
                padding: 1px 1px;
            }

            button {
                font-size: 0.8em;
            }
        }
    </style>
  </head>
```

- ブラウザの開発ツールから見たコード

```
<head>
<meta name="chromevox" content-script="no">
<title>Spreadsheet Editor</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons" nonce=""><link rel="stylesheet" href="/static/macros/client/css/2890476128-mae_html_css_ltr.css">
<script type="text/javascript" src="/static/macros/client/js/1038048745-warden_bin_i18n_warden__ja.js" nonce=""></script>
</head>
```

Answer (score 1):

実際のGoogle Apps Scriptについては分かりませんが、meta tagを追加するために、`addMetaTag`を使用するのはいかがでしょうか。簡単なサンプルは下記のとおりです。

```js
function doGet() {
  const htmlOutput = HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile("index");
  htmlOutput.addMetaTag("viewport", "width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0"); // Here
  return htmlOutput;
}
```

#### Reference:

- [addMetaTag(name, content) in Class HtmlOutput](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/html/html-output?hl=ja#addMetaTag(String,String))